# Retrieve all Cases for given contact for a particular event

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-online

My first custom workflow for CRM 2016 and I'm stuck.
I want to retrieve the count of all created cases for a particular contact for the same event. Put the count in a output variable(parameter). My code is as follows, but i dont know how to proceed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace CRM.Workflows
{
    public class Workflow_CheckExistingCase : CodeActivity
    {
        #region
        [Input("ApplicantID")]
        [ReferenceTarget("contact")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> ApplicantID { get; set; }

        [Input("eventID")]
        [ReferenceTarget("custom_event")]
        public InArgument<EntityReference> eventID { get; set; }

        [Output("Result")]
        public OutArgument<bool> Result { get; set; }
        #endregion

        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {

            var context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            var serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                EntityReference Applicant_ID = ApplicantID.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext);
                EntityReference event_ID = eventID.Get<EntityReference>(executionContext);

                var Did = event_ID.Id;
                var Aid = Applicant_ID.Id;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("Error was created in the workflow:{0}", ex.Message);
                Result.Set(executionContext, "Fail");
                //throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The above code helps me with retrieving Applicant ID and event ID. But I want to check how many cases exists for that applicant and in that event. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You want your custom workflow activity to return a count, so change `OutArgument<bool> Result` into `OutArgument<int> Result`.

The most efficient way of getting the number of cases is using a FetchXml query. See [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118774/fetchxml-get-count-of-records-based-on-a-field-of-a-linked-entity) for an example. You can use Advanced Find in the CRM web interface to create and download the query you need.

Another way is using a `QueryExpression` query and count the number of records being returned.

Assign the count to `OutArgument<int>` Result.